# How can I bind a datatemplate to a observablecollection so that they all show up?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datatemplate

How can I bind a datatemplate to reproduce itself for each item within an observablecollection so that they all show up? Or must I add these as individual controls, at runtime?

So I have a datatemplate:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="QueueItem">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Content="{Binding caseNumber}"></Label>
            <!--TODO: put my other controls for this template here...-->
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And I implement it in xaml here:

```
<ContentControl
               Content="{Binding TestItems}" 
               ContentTemplate="{StaticResource QueueItem}">
</ContentControl>
```

And in my viewmodel there is a instance TestItems of some class I made, and one member of that is caseNumber, so the code above works just fine for me... But now I would like to have an observable collection of that same class, so is it possible/ is there xaml syntax to bind to the collection instance to reproduce the above for each index?

Thanks!

Comment: `ContentControl` is for displaying a single item, while `ItemsControl` is for displaying lists of items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an ItemsControl and use the ItemsTemplate property for your template:

```
<ContentControl>
     <ItemsControl
           ItemsSource="{Binding YourTestItemList}" 
           ItemTemplate="{StaticResource QueueItem}"/>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: thanks! This does not give me any errors, but i see no results on the screen. I wonder if something else additional is needed to make this work? I will see if I can find any demo's online for itemscontrol and observablecollections

Comment: Maybe you have a typo somewhere in your bindings? You can try to increase the log level for binding errors (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409960.aspx)), do you get any more information then in your debug ouput window?

Comment: Thank you so much! your answer was correct, and your comment helped me fix my bug as well! The problem in the end, was that my property was internal instead of public, so after I changed it to public your code worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ItemsControl` instead of `ContentControl`

[Click here for sample code](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/)